# What would happen if you used a 23 inch and a 23.5 inch monitor on Windows?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, gaming

I know that it will work totally fine on the desktop, and with programs open, but how about games? Would they fullscreen across two monitors with such a small size difference, like they would if the monitors were the same size?

Comment: Given that you would be running identical resolutions.  It would be seamless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, In games only the resolution matters, not the size.

If the game supports multiple screens it may just adjust the resolutions or ask you to.

If it does not, the game will only display on the default monitor.

Comment: Thanks, always thought that the size needed to be the same.

Comment: Your welcome... The guys below have provided interesting answers.. my answer weak and simple compared to them, but am glad it worked for you.

Comment: All I needed was a simple and straightforward answer, and this sufficed.

Comment: Tried my 32-inch TV and 23-inch monitors together, it was awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you have monitor **A** and **B** with resolutions *x* and *y*, frequency *u* and *v*  and response time *m* and *n* respectively.If **(x=y; u=v; m=n)**

> *You are Lucky*

Else if **( x=y; u=v but m=!n)** You will experience deja vu of |m-n| *ms*.

The magnitudes of x,y,u,v will be adjusted (automatically or manually by decreasing the magnitude of higher variable) to synchronize the settings(**x=y @ frequency u=v**) . In such cases performance of one of monitors will be bottlenecked.

As there is difference of .5 inch in sizes you may use monitor's onboard settings to adjust the picture position to make it suitable.

Look on the web  if there is any tool/method to slow down response rate (which I doubt) of either choice of your monitors (to make it m=n).

Comment: 0_0 The reasoning behind this math would be interesting. Pretty sure you standardise on one frequency, response time is something I've rarely looked at in multi monitor configurations, and I've run grossly mismatched combinations of monitors before

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to specifically set up your system for it, and that would be at the graphics card options, not the OS.

You'd probably be using something like nvidia surround or AMD eyefinity to do this, and you should refer to the webpage of the appropriate website. I wasn't able to find anything that suggests vertical resolution needs to match.

There's a *few* games that run dual monitor (supreme commander 1 comes to mind) but typically you'll have one monitor sitting at the desktop and one running a game.